# summarise data for multiple variables of a data.frame in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, quantile

I am trying to compute the upper and lower `quartile` of the two `variables` in my `data.frame` across the time period of my interest. The code below gave me single digit for upper and lower value.

```
    set.seed(50)
FakeData <- data.frame(seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to= as.Date("2003-12-31"), by="day"),
                     A = runif(1095, 0,10),
                     D = runif(1095,5,15))
    colnames(FakeData) <- c("Date", "A","D")
    statistics <- FakeData %>% 
              gather(-Date, key = "Variable", value = "Value") %>% 
              mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date)) %>% 
              filter(between(Month,3,5)) %>% 
              mutate(NewDate = ymd(paste("2020", Month,day(Date), sep = "-"))) %>%
              group_by(Variable, NewDate) %>%
              summarise(Upper = quantile(Value,0.75, na.rm = T),
                        Lower = quantile(Value, 0.25, na.rm = T))
```

I would want an output like below (the `Final_output` is what i am interested)

```
Output1 <- data.frame(seq(as.Date("2000-03-01"), to= as.Date("2000-05-31"), by="day"),
                       Upper = runif(92, 0,10), lower = runif(92,5,15), Variable = rep("A",92))
colnames(Output1)[1] <- "Date"
Output2 <- data.frame(seq(as.Date("2000-03-01"), to= as.Date("2000-05-31"), by="day"),
                      Upper = runif(92, 2,10), lower = runif(92,5,15), Variable = rep("D",92))
colnames(Output2)[1] <- "Date"
Final_Output<- bind_rows(Output1,Output2)
```

Comment: I've read your question 10 times and I cannot figure out what you actually want or why the code you provided doesn't give you the desired output. I suggest you provide a smaller example (6 records should do it) with the expected output. :)

Comment: You should use `set.seed(1)` or similar to ensure that the random numbers you generate with `runif` are the same each time you run the code.

Comment: Thank you guys- I just want to compute the upper and lower quartile of the two variables. @AndrewChisholm i updated the question, using `set.seed()`

Comment: Try using `dplyr::filter()` and `dplyr::summarise()` so there is no doubt you are calling the required functions.

Comment: Thank you so much @Andrew - it worked. using `dplyr::summarise()` solved my problem.

Comment: @Hydro - glad to have helped.  Perhaps you could show your appreciation and mark the comment as adding value.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose you a `data.table` solution. In fact there are several ways to do that.

The final steps (apply quartile by group on the `Value` variable) could be translated into (if you want, as in your example, two columns):

```r
statistics[,.('p25' = quantile(get('Value'), probs = 0.25), 'p75' = quantile(get('Value'), probs = 0.75)),
           by = c("Variable", "NewDate")]
```

If you prefer long-formatted output:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(statistics)

statistics[,.(lapply(get('Value'), quantile, probs = .25,.75)) ,
by = c("Variable", "NewDate")]
```

## All steps together

It's probably better if you chose to use `data.table` to do all steps using data.table verbs. I will assume your data have the structure similar to the dataframe you generated and arranged, i.e.

```r
statistics <- FakeData %>% 
  gather(-Date, key = "Variable", value = "Value")
```

In that case, `mutate` and `filter` steps would become

```r
statistics[,`:=`(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date))]
statistics <- statistics[Month %between% c(3,5)]
statistics[, NewDate = :ymd(paste("2020", Month,day(Date), sep = "-"))]
```

And choose the final step you prefer, e.g.

```r
statistics[,.('p25' = quantile(get('Value'), probs = 0.25), 'p75' = quantile(get('Value'), probs = 0.75)),
           by = c("Variable", "NewDate")]
```

Comment: Thank you @linog I am still eager to know why i am not getting the desired result through my code- I used the code before and was working fine but not sure why its lending me wrong the wrong answer.

Comment: In that case I don't understand the difference between what you want and you end up with. The code produces the desired quartiles and looking at the dataframe, they seem to have the same structure. What would you want ?